# How to find the accuracy of a tracing task?

Tags: matlab, ipad, geometry, curve-fitting

Hello I am doing a research on how well Parkinson patients can perform tracing task on an Ipad (i.e. tracing shapes on Ipad using their fingers). The patients needs to trace three shapes, a horizontal line, a circle, and a zig-zag line, and the Ipad is able to record the time and position of the finger and process the data with Matlab.

I am able to find the accuracy of the traced straight line by measuring the variance of the y position of the traced line. Similarly, I can measure the radial variance of the traced circle. However I am having trouble figuring out the simplest way to measure the accuracy of the traced zig-zag line because it's shape is not as consistent as the straight line/circle.

Is there an easy way of measuring how well a traced zigzag line fit a real zigzag line? (note Assuming I have the x and y position of the actual zig zag)

Comment: If you have a line nor horizontal neither vertical, you should compute the [distance from a point to a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line). The use it in some way (like the variance). Why not consider the zig-zag as a series of lines? (I think you should have to choose the criteria when around "nodes" the traced line is near both the previous and the following segment)

Comment: My issue was that the zig-zag had 30 segments so I was hoping for a non-tedious solution to this. But I guess if i try to find the closest distance from each point to all the line then I can just use the minimum distance as the closest one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest investigating general curve distance/similarity metrics. There are different metrics for measuring distances between curves (Hausdorff distance, Frétchet Distance etc.). These specialised distance measures can handle cases where average variance would suggest good similarity, where as in reality are too dissimilar (see the linked paper for examples).

I think, in this case, what you need is [Frétchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance). See [this paper](https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kreve101/asci/ag-cfdbt-95.pdf) for a comparison with Hausdorff distance and details on calculating it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at Marcoresk's comment I think the simplest thing I can do is compute the distance of each traced points with each line segment in the zig-zag pattern then find the smallest distance between each point and the line segment and use the variance of these distances as accuracy.

Comment: What you describe is Hausdorff distance (discreet) (instead of variance, find the maximum among all the minimum distances). It may not indicate actual similarity though (of course, please give it a try, make sure you subdivide both your curves so that individual line segments are of some uniform length, smaller the better.). See this answer for why I recommend Frétchet distance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764286/hausdorff-and-fr%C3%A9chet-distances. You can use DTW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping algorithm for computing Fretchet distances for polylines.